# Make autolayout contraints to fill different screen sizes in Swift with variable vertical spaces

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, autolayout

I want to make my autolayout to fill all the screen sizes from iphone 5s to 8s. The solution I'm looking for is making vertical spaces greater if the screen is bigger. But, I haven't figure it out, I know that I can fix vertical spaces equals or greater than, but it does not work.

The first image is iPhone 5s, and the second is iPhone 8s, the elements in 8s screen should have more vertical space in the second screen. I would try any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at `UIStackView`? That is generally what's used for this task.

Comment: What about putting the whole layout inside a stack view, set up constraints so that it'll fill the screen and setting up Equal Spacing for it?

Comment: What is *android*?

Comment: I solved the edition issues. And I'll try with the stackView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your UI elements, I suggest to put it in a vertical Stack view.
Then you have to fix some constraints to fill the whole screen like this :

- Stack View.Top = Top Layout Guide.Bottom + Standard *//Constraint to the top of the screen*
- Bottom Layout Guide.Top = Stack View.Bottom + Standard *//Constraint to the bottom of the screen*
- Axis : vertical
- Alignement : Fill
- Distribution : Fill equally or proportionnaly or other
- Spacing between each view

Try this. Here is Apple Documentation about Auto Layout if you want to go any further or see some examples : [Apple documentation - Stack vviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1)

Answer (score -1):

Usually you can achieve better spacing with blank (clear color) views.
You can try to insert "blank views" instead of spaces.
Like this, vertical: "V:|[blank0][obj][blank1][obj2][blank2][obj3][blank3]|"
Then you tell all the "blank views" objects to have the same height.

Comment: Why was my answer down voted? This works in iOS 8, while Stack Views are restricted to iOS 9+. Also, both approaches are well described here: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/goodbye-spacer-views-hello-layout-guides/